# MYSQL não lista quando rodo o comando 'netstat -ntlp'

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, laravel, centos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aparentemente meu MYSQL está funcionando normal, porém quando rodo o comando:

```
netstat -ntlp
```

O resultado é este:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como se o MYSQL não estivesse rodando.

Comment: Rodando ele está, quando você roda apenas o netstat consegue encontrar alguma conexão na porta 3306 ? e seu mysql está aberto para conexões externas?

Comment: Quando dou o netstat não aparece a porta 3306, como mostra na imagem. Não sei responder a segunda pergunta, eu apenas baixei o mysql e dei o start